# mysql creating sort index making queries slow

Tags: mysql, sorting, indexing

We have a view table the query for the view is pasted below. The problem is that whenever we try to query items view our database start making sorting index which make the over all time of our response very slow.

```
CREATE VIEW items_view AS
SELECT item_detail.*, item.name, item.description, item.thumbnail_url, item.large_image_url, item.ios_url, item.android_url, item.vr_url, item.vr_updated_url, item.webgl_url, item.video_url, item.quest_url,
item.is_transferable, item.ip_id, item.brand_id, item.edition_id, item.currency_id, item.category_id, item.rarity_id, item.type_id, item.asset_id, item.artist_id, item.art_collection_id,
IFNULL(item.variation_id, 0) AS variation_id,
item.series_id, item.set_id, item.is_tradable, item.number_minted, ip.name AS ip_name, brand.name As brand_name, brand.value AS brand_image,
edition.name AS edition_name, type.name As type_name, artist.name AS artist_name, art_collection.name AS art_collection_name,
IFNULL(variation.name, '') As variation_name, variation.value AS variation_value, category.name As category_name, asset.name AS asset_name, asset.value AS asset_image,
rarity.name As rarity_name, currency.symbol, currency.code AS currency_code, currency.name AS currency_name, series.name AS series_name, sets.name AS set_name,
CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ' ,users.last_name) as owner_name, users.username AS owner_username, users.is_public_inventory, users.role, users.pub_key,
auctions.id as auction_id, auctions.expire_at as auction_expire_at, max(ab.bid_amount) AS highest_bid_amount, IF(COUNT(auctions.id) > 0 AND !auctions.is_completed AND !auctions.is_deleted
, true, false) AS is_auction, auctions.start_amount AS auction_start_amount, auctions.reserved_amount AS auction_reserved_amount, auctions.buy_now_amount AS auction_buy_now_amount,
auctions.created_at as auction_created_at, auctions.status AS auction_status, auctions.is_extended AS auction_extended, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, now(), auctions.expire_at) AS auction_expire_seconds FROM item
LEFT JOIN base_lookup AS ip ON item.ip_id = ip.id
LEFT JOIN base_lookup AS brand ON item.brand_id = brand.id
LEFT JOIN base_lookup AS edition ON item.edition_id = edition.id
LEFT JOIN base_lookup AS category ON item.category_id = category.id
LEFT JOIN base_lookup AS type ON item.type_id = type.id
LEFT JOIN base_lookup AS variation ON item.variation_id = variation.id
LEFT JOIN base_lookup AS rarity ON item.rarity_id = rarity.id
LEFT JOIN base_lookup AS series ON item.series_id = series.id
LEFT JOIN base_lookup AS sets ON item.set_id = sets.id
LEFT JOIN base_lookup AS asset ON item.asset_id = asset.id
LEFT JOIN base_lookup AS artist ON item.artist_id = artist.id
LEFT JOIN base_lookup AS art_collection ON item.art_collection_id = art_collection.id
INNER JOIN item_detail ON item.id = item_detail.parent_id
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = item_detail.owner_id
LEFT JOIN currency ON currency.id = item.currency_id
LEFT JOIN auctions on (item_detail.id = auctions.item_detail_id AND auctions.is_deleted = 0 AND auctions.is_completed = 0)
LEFT JOIN auction_bidding ab on auctions.id = ab.auction_id
WHERE item_detail.is_active = 1
group by item_detail.id
order by item_detail.id;
```

One of the query we are doing on this items_view that is stuck in making sorting index

```
SELECT 
  `id`, `code`, `name`, `large_image_url`, 
  `thumbnail_url`, `medium_thumbnail_url`, `symbol`, `ip_name`, `owner_id`, 
  `auction_id`, `is_auction`, `highest_bid_amount`, `auction_expire_at`, 
  `auction_start_amount`, `enable_sale`, `owner_name`, `role`, `amount`, 
  `auction_expire_seconds`, `rarity_name`, `ip_content`, `asset_content` 
FROM `items_view` AS `items_view` 
WHERE `items_view`.`transaction_hash` IS NOT NULL AND 
  `items_view`.`lobby_name` = 'live' AND 
  `items_view`.`is_tradable` = 1 AND 
  `items_view`.`is_transferring` = 0 AND 
  `items_view`.`is_locked` = 0 AND 
  `items_view`.`enable_sale` = true AND 
  `items_view`.`is_auction` = 0 
ORDER BY `items_view`.`item_order` ASC LIMIT 24, 24;
```

can any give any suggest what are we doing wrong here!

Edited:
link to explain run against the above query
[link to csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PtCGtVXzfgcBsDDspAj5EeyBFvbnIHLG/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN PLAN` details (see [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execution-plan-information.html))

Comment: 'View processing is not optimized:

It is not possible to create an index on a view.

Indexes can be used for views processed using the merge algorithm. However, a view that is processed with the temptable algorithm is unable to take advantage of indexes on its underlying tables (although indexes can be used during generation of the temporary tables).' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-restrictions.html What algorithm did you specify/allow to default to?

Comment: @Lukk  EXPLAIN plan added in the question that is ran against the above query

Comment: @P.Salmon We are not creating index on the view its the mysql server who is doing this everything we query this view. we haven't specified any algorithm I think default one might be running. can you tell me how to find the underlying algorithm it is using ?

Comment: Show create view items_view https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html

Comment: @P.Salmon this is what I got after running that command `ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED`

Comment: Be aware that a MySQL View is never "materialized".  OTOH, the constructed Select may "materialize" a 'derived' table in it.

Comment: Do you get the same results if you remove `group by item_detail.id`?

Comment: @RickJames No if I remove group by and order by I am not getting it

Comment: @rickjames is there any problem of tables not properly associated because I am joining one of the table that is not directly associated with a table rather it is associated with one other table I am joining with

Comment: @SabihAhmed - I was trying to ascertain whether the group-by was unnecessary.  (Removing the order-by would lead to a different sort order.)  However, it might be useful to remove the order-by from the VIEW since there is an order-by in the SELECT.

Comment: @SabihAhmed - I don't think your question about "properly associated" is a problem.  (but I am not sure -- it's all rather complex)

Comment: @RickJames yes you are right order by is unnecessary in the query. The question about associate came from an article I read from here https://www.programmersought.com/article/96936302147/

Comment: @Rickjames in this article they tell about how join affect our query if the tables are not directly associated. In our case we have one or two joins that are not associated from the main table direct. so that made me wondering whether its the same problem we are facing or not

Comment: @SabihAhmed - The query in that article seems to have two inefficiencies.  `product` needs `INDEX(level_id)` and `rankUser` needs `INDEX(Create_time)`.  Also, the Optimizer decided to use the "join_buffer" since it did not find a suitable index (or maybe instead of using the index).  And probably each of those `LEFT JOINs` returns exactly one row, but the Optimizer does not have any way to know it.  So it is forced to make a sort pass -- which is the slow part...

Comment: Then they misinterpreted the Explainof the second query; it does not scan 67452 rows, but only 10.  (This is a deficiency in Explain when LIMIT is present.)  [With this many flaws in the analysis this early in that link, I hate to continue; please do not expect to learn much from it.]

Comment: (I can't resist.)  Without the `ORDER BY`, there is no need to sort; it simply picks the most convenient 10 rows (probably the first 10 in the table, however it is stored).  Oops, I made a mistake above; `product` seems to have `INDEX(level_id)`.  Still, the possible existence of more than 1 row necessitates the temp table and sort.

Comment: Oh, the 3rd query begins to "prove" some of what I said above.  Hmmm... I guess I don't know what he means by "directly related" and "direct correlation".  Perhaps he means that the JOIN is guaranteed to deliver 1 row.  When all JOINs are like that (query 3), the LIMIT on the "first" table can be used for terminating the execution.  Clever.   I think I will read their other blogs.

Comment: @SabihAhmed - Back to your Query.  Do all the JOINs read only 1 row?  A big similarity between your query and theirs -- both have ORDER BY + LIMIT, yet initially the queries cannot use an index to stop at the limit.

Comment: The MAX() seems "wrong".